# Custom image field with drupal(7) views 3

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, cck

I've created custom theme look for one of my fields in views, and added field field_field_services_text_link[0]['rendered']['#markup'];?>. I tried to do same with my another image field, but it doesnt works. I used field_field_services_image[0]['rendered']]['uri']; ?>, but something wrong in this code. Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshoot this, perhaps the following would help.  Paste it in your theme file instead of what you have above

```
<?php print_r($field_field_services_image); ?>
```

the print_r function will show you the structure of the **array** ($field_field_services_image) you're trying to work with and can show you whether the structure is exactly as you'd expect.  Perhaps there's a problem somewhere in the [0]['rendered']... portion, and you can check that.  It may be empty somewhere, etc...

Comment: I tried this way, but since im not strong in php, i just created another image field, and used standarg render(output) in theme file, and paste there my code

Comment: Oh great!  So you used print render($content['field_field_services_image']);?  That's even better than digging around the field structure anyway!

Comment: no, everything was even simplier. In my custom views-image-field.tpl.php i used <?php print $output; ?> to insert my image into part of other code, i mentionned above. Here is what i've got:
<a href="<?php print $row->field_field_services_link[0]['raw']['url']; ?>" class="service_link_bottom"><?php print $output; ?><span class="some-class"><?php print $row->field_field_services_text_link[0]['rendered']['#markup'];?></span></a>

Answer (score 0):

You could always see whats being output with a var dump or even better, the devel module.